# Why does my analogRead work on Teensy but not Arduino Uno?

Tags: arduino-uno, analogread, teensy

I have successfully made a voltage measurement circuit on my Teensy 3.1 that reads a voltage coming out of digital pin 0 set high and coming back into an analog pin A0 to read voltage.

Basically:

```c
int timer = 100;
int ColA = 0;
int Output;

// Setting digital pin functions

void setup()
{                
  Serial.begin(38400);
  pinMode(0, OUTPUT);

}

// Program

void loop()                     
{ 
  digitalWrite(0, HIGH);
  delay(timer);
  Output = analogRead(A0);
  Serial.println(Output);
  delay(timer);
}
```

It works fine with my circuit on a Teensy 3.1 running 3.3v however when i run this code on an Arduino Uno running 5v wired exactly the same way I just get this print out of numbers that cycles back and forth from ~128 down to 0 and back constantly.

Any insight on the differences here would be great. I need the 5v micro-controller to run a 4051 multiplexer!

Comment: What happens if your remove the `digitalWrite` from the loop and put it in setup? And do you have an oscilloscope? That'll tell you what electrickery is happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're still using D0 as your output on the Uno then yes you are doomed to failure.

D0 and D1 are the serial port. You are using that to communicate with the PC. You cannot use them for any other purpose at the same time.

Pick a different IO pin to be your voltage source.